# Как реализовать JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Temp>(jsonExample)

Tags: c#, json

Есть некий Json

```
var jsonExample=   { "name":"A",
      "mas":["listA","listA"],
      "obj": {
        "svg": "https://flagcdn.com/br.svg",
        "png": "https://flagcdn.com/w320/br.png"
      }
    }
```

Также есть некий class Temp, в который нужно дессериализовать

```
public class Temp {
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string mas0 { get; set; }
    public string Svg { get; set; }
}
```

как реализовать **JsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonExample)** , чтобы данные сразу мапились в Temp, без создания промежуточного класса наподобии

```
public class Obj {
    public string svg { get; set; }
    public string png { get; set; }
}
public class Temp {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<string> mas { get; set; }
    public Obj obj { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Создавать свой кастомный конвертор, который будет разбирать JSON и заполнять нужные свойства на  основе полученного. Так просто несостыковку типов (где в JSON у вас массив, а в классе вдруг обычное свойство конкретного типа) вы не уберете.

Comment: _без создания промежуточного класса_ можно только через `JsonConverter`, но поверьте, это будет сильно сложнее написать, чем с промежуточной моделью данных. Поправил кстати вам модель в вопросе, а то она нерабочая была.